# Some questions of automate the process of iOS builds

Tags: ios, bash, build, keychain

Recently,I try to automate the process of `iOS builds` using bash scripts.

I'm building the app,code signing the file using `xcodebuild`, and then pack the project using `xcrun`.
In `xcode`,we can set some information easily,(`Summary->iOS` `Application Target->`...)

but,how can I set the information without `Xcode`,I want to do that using bash scripts,like   modify `info-plist` or other configuration files,does it works? how can I solve this question?

**The second question:**

Because I want to automate `iOS builds` in server,  I need to import `certificates(.p12)` which clients give me into `keychain` automatically,the question is how can I export .p12 file automatically from keychain when clients give me the name of code signing.

**Can you provide me some information of automating the process of iOS builds using bash scripts？** Or do you have realize the function? Please give me some clues about that, or the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject custom build settings by passing `KEY=VALUE` arguments to `xcodebuild`. You can then put these into Info.plist values with `${MY_BUILD_SETTING}`.

Comment: Thank you for your help,yeah,I can inject some settings like this : xcodebuild TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY=1 IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=4.3 to set values of Devices and Deployment Target.But I don't find arguments  to set Bundle Identifier;version;Build,and have good solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I found that we can use plistbuddy to set values about info.plist,like that /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set:CFBundleShortVersionString ${version_version}" ${plist_path}

plistbuddy is a tool which can modify plist file well,using   /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -h to find help.
Hope that can help other people!